# WSOD with Devel module

Tags: users, debugging

A website I am working on is having a WSOD problem, but only on the permissions page. I narrowed this down to the devel module, because when enable, WSOD permission page, devel module unenabled, clean permission page. Any idea what is causing this?

Answer (score 1):

The solution to this problem was to un-enable the Devel module, uninstall the Devel module, clear the cache, and rebuild permission, then re-enable the Devel module. Not sure that clearing the cache and rebuilding permissions was necessary, but this solution did allow the Devel module to be enabled and view the permission page.