# Devel module and the WSOD on login

Tags: debugging, wsod

I have a lot of trouble with the WSOD and have looked around quite few posts; like [WSOD with Devel module](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/121002/wsod-with-devel-module) and [How to see the error messages when I get the white screen of death?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/7560/how-to-see-the-error-messages-when-i-get-the-white-screen-of-death) as well as https://www.drupal.org/node/1692262

After reading the posts the best thing to do was to uninstall the the devel module, once i did that the WSOD is gone, but what if you need the devel module?

I'm struggling to get the errors up and work out where i have gone wrong. Doesn't Krumo need devel?

Comment: Find out what the actual error message is (using the info in the posts you linked to, every WSOD will have one), then work out what it's complaining about, and go about fixing it...that might involve reporting a bug to the devel (or other) module if that's the problem, changing your server config, removing other modules that are conflicting, etc. There isn't enough information in your question to give anything other than guesses, a person with access to the server needs to do the initial debugging work

Comment: Hi Clive thanks for that I will edit my question, sorry for the mix up.

Comment: /update.php can sometimes be helpful in getting information about WSOD as well.

Comment: @clive I've tried re-editing but this issue is slightly beyond me.

Comment: @sareed i ran that about 10 times and it did nothing.

Comment: Is the WSOD site wide or a single page like the first links question?

Comment: @sareed it is just on the home page when you are logged in.

Comment: Ok, you aren't trying to use dpm on the homepage by any chance? The module is just enabled, correct?

Comment: If you check your web server logs (apache/nginx/fpm) you should find the real error (WSOD is a fatal that Drupal can't recover from basically, so Drupal itself won't be able to tell you what's wrong). Krumo does need Devel in this context, but devel won't be catching the errors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a complete solution, but can help.

If you want to look at something but dont want to spend the time investigating your site's aversion to the devel module, then drupal core's [watchdog](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/watchdog/7) call can be helpful.  Also, I am assuming you have dblog or weblog module enabled to catch the error messages.  To make it more readable, like a krumo output, I often add my [Explain](https://github.com/developerweeks/weeks_drupal_tools/blob/master/weeks_drupal_tools.php) function to a custom module somewhere. Then in the place where I would have used `krumo($target);` I use `watchdog('bug_hunt', explain($target, 5, 'target') );` and go to /admin/reports/dblog and filter for bug_hunt.  That 5 is arbitrary in this case; 4 steps into something can get you `target->field_one[und][0][value] = Content`.Since I have that function terminating the recursion with html line breaks, it reads well in the log pages.

I started doing this when I was trying to expound on processes that did not have a page for krumo to inject into (maestro module workflows, etc).  Since then, it has been a reliable fall-back method for me.

The better solution would be to spend the time finding why devel crashes your site, as it might be an issue that will appear again later on.

Comment: Hi  and thanks @DeveloperWeeks where would i place the watchdog code? No I don't have dblog or weblog.

Comment: Install dblog module.  This will let you go to /admin/reports/dblog and see all the entries of errors and notices that drupal records.  It will also enable you, if you have command line and drush, to use the command `drush ws --tail` and see the errors come in while you load the page.

Comment: thanks for that, i don't have drush yet, but all I know is now that i have uninstalled devel things work fine.